# How to send data from view to controller on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-2

How can I invoke controller action and send which values are selected in drop down lists in time when button was clicked? Here is example how my .cshtml looks like. This is just example, generally I need to collect much data from current view in time when button was clicked.

```
<body>
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownList("Name")
        <br />
        @Html.DropDownList("Age")
        <br />
        @Html.DropDownList("Gender")
        <br />
        @using (Html.BeginForm("FindPerson", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <input type="submit" value="Find" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This seems like a very basic question - have you tried looking for a tutorial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the data to be submitted to the controller, the inputs must appear within the `<form>` tag.

For example:

```
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("FindPerson", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
        {

            @Html.DropDownList("Name")
            <br />
            @Html.DropDownList("Age")
            <br />
            @Html.DropDownList("Gender")
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Find" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thx. To help someone else how to use this in controller: public ActionResult FindPerson(FormCollection form)

Answer (score 2):

inside the @using (Html.BeginForm("FindPerson", "MyController", FormMethod.Post)) you should put your inputs.

You have your inputs outside the Form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FindPerson", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    @Html.DropDownList("Name")
    <br />
    @Html.DropDownList("Age")
    <br />
    @Html.DropDownList("Gender")
    <br />

        <input type="submit" value="Find" />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First u need the Model to bind your data.

```
 public class TestModel
    {
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; } 
        ...
    }
```

then you need to wrap your dropLists in form tag

```
<form method='post'>
 @Html.DropDownList("Age")
</form>
```

and action to recive posted data

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult YourAction(TestModel model)//selected data here
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

inside the @using (Html.BeginForm("NameOfActionMethod", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post)) you should put your inputs.

You have your inputs outside the Form

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("NameOfActionMethod", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
   <input type="submit" value="Find" />
}
```